# Servo Directional Control Using Two Button Inputs

Tags: button, arduino, rotation, servo

I want a standard servo to rotate 180 degrees when button 1 is pressed and released.  But I want the servo to rotate back to the initial position only when button 2 is being held down (& to stop rotating once button 2 is released).  The arduino code I have now correctly allows the servo to make a full rotation 180 degrees with a press and release of button 1, but the servo also incorrectly rotates back to the initial position with a press and release of button 2 instead of stopping once released.  Any help with the following code would be much appreciated:

```
#include <Servo.h>
Servo myservo;

int pos;

const int buttonPin = 2;
const int buttonPin2 = 3;
int buttonState = 0;
int buttonState2 = 0;

void setup()
{
  myservo.attach(9);

  pinMode(buttonPin, INPUT);
  pinMode(buttonPin2,INPUT);

}
void loop()

{

  buttonState = digitalRead(buttonPin);
  buttonState2 = digitalRead(buttonPin2); 

  if (buttonState == HIGH) {  
    pos=180;
    myservo.write(180);    

  }

  if (buttonState2 == HIGH) {  
    pos-=1;
    myservo.write(pos); 

  } 
}
```

Comment: Can you tell me what you get on a single press and release on button2.Dont press it for long just a sudden press and release.check it and update me

Answer (score 0):

You don't have any delay in your loop. Your `pos-=1;` line will be executed with high frequency, and the servo is not able to follow that.

A simple solution would be to introduce a short delay (e.g. `delay(20);`) after your `myservo.write(pos);` so the servo has some time to actually reach the new position.

Comment: `delay()` would avoid problem but its a bit deprecated use.Better to use `millis()`

Comment: `delay()` is not deprecated and it does the job just fine. Obviously you don't get any concurrency, which is why in bigger projects you want to [avoid it](https://playground.arduino.cc/Code/AvoidDelay). But for this, it is just right IMO.

Comment: Yeah by deprecated i meant use of it is not well promoted.think tht sounds same

Comment: Thanks to both of you.

Comment: If we could solve your problem, don't forget to mark one answer as solution :)